# CMake a project with OpenCV in Mac OS X - 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found

Tags: macos, opencv, cmake

I wrote a simple opencv project containing only a `main.cpp` file:

```
// main.cpp
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main()
{
    cv::Mat I = cv::imread("img.png");
    cv::imshow("img",I);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Then to build it, I wrote a `CMakeLists.txt` like this, which is actually copied from http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

In terminal, first I ran `cmake .` and a `Makefile` was generated. Then I ran `make` and got the following error:

```
fatal error: 
  'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
         ^
......
```

It seems the compiler cannot find OpenCV include dir. But I don't know where to add it to the `CMakeLists.txt`. My platform is Mac OS X 10.10, and OpenCV include and lib files have been installed at `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` already. However, in Ubuntu, the compiler can find it and successfully build the project.

So what is a correct `CMakeLists.txt` in Mac OS X?

Comment: According to the error description, it seems that CMake have found OpenCV on your Mac (inclusion of file `opencv/cv.h` has been processed successfully). But either that OpenCV installation is too old, or not all OpenCV components are installed, so include file `opencv2/opencv.hpp` does not exist. You can check existence of both include files manually under `/usr/local/include`.

Answer (score 6):

I finally actually read the header of /opt/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVConfig.cmake installed via MacPorts.  To use in external projects, it instructs to include:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MY_TARGET_NAME ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

(simply adding include_directories to my CMakeLists.txt fixed this for me)